# Trigger an Airflow ETL job by fetching Incremental data from a Database

Tags: mongodb, airflow

I want to perform some transformations on the data resting in MongoDB and inserted the transformed data into ElasticSearch via an Airflow DAG. 
While I can write operators to fetch the data and perform transformations, the challenges is that I want to trigger a DAG only when new data has been inserted into a collection and fetch that new data for transformation. I have read about Sensors but I haven't been able to find a concrete solution.
Can someone please advise?

EDIT:
I apologise for not explaining the problem properly.

The following are the tasks I have to do:
1. Whenever new documents are inserted into MongoDB, fetch the documents and do some JSON transformation. 
2. Stream the transformed JSON data to the next task where further processing is done and insert the data into Elasticsearch index.

My idea to fetch only the new data is to:
1. Insert a unique incremental batch_id along with the data in MongoDB.
2. Fetch the max batch_id for the previous job and poke MongoDB for incremented batch_id.
3. If the new incremented batch_id is present, fetch data.

The above idea works but I'm not sure if that is the right approach.

The current pipeline is as below:

[image: The 1st task is a sensor]

Comment: Please show what you have attempted, and explain what specifically fails.

Comment: Hi @Dragonthoughts , I have added more details to my question now.